# How to find installed pure-ftpd version?

Tags: linux, ftp, pureftpd

Trying to find which version of pure-ftpd my server is using, in order to help troubleshoot a probably FTP client issue.

I'm on CentOS 6.7, but would prefer a more generic/universal method, if possible.

I found this method (https://askubuntu.com/questions/153491/how-to-find-pure-ftpd-version), but it only works for Ubuntu, or other systems (Debian-based, etc) that are using the apt package manager.

I suppose something with the yum package manager might work?  But again, would prefer a more generic/universal method, if possible.

I tried looking at the man page, and invoking the pure-ftpd command, but found nothing to help indicate which version is installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This should work universally:

```
$ pure-ftpd --help | head -1
pure-ftpd v1.0.36 [privsep]
```

Comment: huh, for some reason `pure-ftpd --help` on my particular server doesn't output the version; but if it did, as the first line, this would work.  

On mine, I just get 
`-0 --notruncate`, which is the first line of the output of `pure-ftpd --help`.

Thanks, though.

Comment: I guess different versions of pure-ftpd output the help message slightly differently?  I'm on 1.0.42 (as reported by yum).

Thank you, though, that could still be helpful.

Comment: As a complement to @EEAA's answer: on my CentOS 6.10 system, I've just realized that `pure-ftpd --help` outputs the version in the first line **only if I'm root or I've sudoed the command**.

Comment: @AbVog I can confirm this sudoed thing for Manjaro too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this works:

`yum info pure-ftpd`

But still wondering if there's a more generic way?

Answer (score -2):

Open your Terminal and type the following command

```
apt-cache showpkg pure-ftpd
```

Comment: This is Debian-style, not Red Hat-style which uses yum. OP specifies that he is using CentOS, which is Red Hat-style yum, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: Still potentially useful for others, though, who may be on Debian-style systems.  I was hoping for something universal, though, but sadly nothing yet.  But at least we have a useful collection of things to try.